# How To Create extra download page on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a separate download page in WordPress when the visitor clicks on a download button having link https://example.com/(any_post)/download, it will open a download page having the destination url.

What i have done?

I have created a custom field that takes link from post for this I uses below:

```
// Meta Box Class: DownloadLinkMetaBox
// Get the field value: $metavalue = get_post_meta( $post_id, $field_id, true );
class DownloadLinkMetaBox{

    private $screen = array(
        'post',
                        
    );

    private $meta_fields = array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Download Link',
                    'id' => 'download_id',
                    'type' => 'text',
                )

    );

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_fields' ) );
    }

    public function add_meta_boxes() {
        foreach ( $this->screen as $single_screen ) {
            add_meta_box(
                'DownloadLink',
                __( 'DownloadLink', '' ),
                array( $this, 'meta_box_callback' ),
                $single_screen,
                'normal',
                'default'
            );
        }
    }

    public function meta_box_callback( $post ) {
        wp_nonce_field( 'DownloadLink_data', 'DownloadLink_nonce' );
        $this->field_generator( $post );
    }
    public function field_generator( $post ) {
        $output = '';
        foreach ( $this->meta_fields as $meta_field ) {
            $label = '<label for="' . $meta_field['id'] . '">' . $meta_field['label'] . '</label>';
            $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $meta_field['id'], true );
            if ( empty( $meta_value ) ) {
                if ( isset( $meta_field['default'] ) ) {
                    $meta_value = $meta_field['default'];
                }
            }
            switch ( $meta_field['type'] ) {
                default:
                                    $input = sprintf(
                                        '<input %s id="%s" name="%s" type="%s" value="%s">',
                                        $meta_field['type'] !== 'color' ? 'style="width: 100%"' : '',
                                        $meta_field['id'],
                                        $meta_field['id'],
                                        $meta_field['type'],
                                        $meta_value
                                    );
            }
            $output .= $this->format_rows( $label, $input );
        }
        echo '<table class="form-table"><tbody>' . $output . '</tbody></table>';
    }

    public function format_rows( $label, $input ) {
        return '<tr><th>'.$label.'</th><td>'.$input.'</td></tr>';
    }

    public function save_fields( $post_id ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['DownloadLink_nonce'] ) )
            return $post_id;
        $nonce = $_POST['DownloadLink_nonce'];
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'DownloadLink_data' ) )
            return $post_id;
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
            return $post_id;
        foreach ( $this->meta_fields as $meta_field ) {
            if ( isset( $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] ) ) {
                switch ( $meta_field['type'] ) {
                    case 'email':
                        $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] = sanitize_email( $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] );
                        break;
                    case 'text':
                        $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] );
                        break;
                }
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_field['id'], $_POST[ $meta_field['id'] ] );
            } else if ( $meta_field['type'] === 'checkbox' ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_field['id'], '0' );
            }
        }
    }
}

if (class_exists('DownloadLinkMetabox')) {
    new DownloadLinkMetabox;
};
```

That takes link perfectly and also able to show on front but not able to create another page.

Below code used to show in frontend

```
add_action( 'generate_after_entry_header', 'wpsh_single_posts_custom_meta_fields', 9 );
function wpsh_single_posts_custom_meta_fields(){
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $post   = get_post( $post_id );
$download_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'download_id' );

        if( $download_id ) { ?>
        
<div class="wp-block-buttons aligncenter">
                            <div class="wp-block-button">
                                <a style='text-transform: uppercase;' href="<?php the_permalink();?>download/" class="wp-block-button__link has-vivid-cyan-blue-background-color download ripple">
                                    <i class="material-icons">
                                        <svg class="icon" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                            <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                                            <path d="M19.35 10.04C18.67 6.59 15.64 4 12 4 9.11 4 6.6 5.64 5.35 8.04 2.34 8.36 0 10.91 0 14c0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6h13c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5 0-2.64-2.05-4.78-4.65-4.96zM17 13l-5 5-5-5h3V9h4v4h3z" />
                                        </svg>
                                    </i> Download</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<?php }
}
```

Above code will show button if the download id have link and the button have link example.com/any_post/download. Now here i don't know how to serve the link that the download_id holds of the post from it visits to .../download

I'm thinking to create a template page that serve the link but not able to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your functions:

**Once you have added all your code make sure to flush your rewrite rules by going to: Settings > Permalinks and clicking 'save changes'**

Set your rewrite rules:

```
function custom_add_rewrite_rule(){
    
   
    $posts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type' => 'post') );
    
    if( $posts ){
        
        foreach($posts as $post ){
            
            add_rewrite_rule( 
                $post->post_name . '/download/?$', 
                'index.php?name=' . $post->post_name . '&post_action=download&post_id=' . $post->ID, 
                'top' 
            );   
        }
    }

}
add_action('init', 'custom_add_rewrite_rule');
```

add your [`query_vars`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars):

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "post_action";
    $vars[] = "post_id";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

then include your custom template:

```
function include_custom_template($template){

    if( get_query_var('post_action') && get_query_var('post_action') == 'download'){
        $template = get_template_directory() ."/download.php";
    } 
     
    return $template;    
}

add_filter('template_include', 'include_custom_template');
```

and finally make a file called `download.php` in your theme root and call your parameters

```
$download_id = get_post_meta( get_query_var('post_id'), 'download_id' );
//Your Code
```

Comment: Did exactly what you said but still getting 404; meaning not able to call the download.php

Comment: Now, Working forget to do permalink step. Glad achieved what i want to do.

Comment: Everytime i publish post i have to do permalink step without this its showing 404 is there any way to solve this?

Comment: see this answer [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/263285/35799](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/263285/35799)

Comment: followed but didn't work but this one worked anyone need see this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/334880/how-do-i-flush-rewrite-rules